# Use UWP MediaCapture from WPF-application

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

We have tried finding a good media-library for recording videos in WPF, but it seems most fall short one way or another. However, the one existing in UWP seems to be quite competent, and more in line with what we want.

I have experimented a bit, and got an UWP AppService up and running, and I was able to take a picture from WPF-application using a command. The next step was to get a video recorded, and this is where it got tricky.

I created two commands in the same BackgroundTask and kind of hoped they would be executed from the same instance so that I could store the MediaCapture-object between commands, and start the recording in one and stop it in another.
However, they seem to spawn two separate instances, so I cannot store any state between the two commands to the AppService.

Am I able to solve this problem via some configuration or another approach that would work better for my specific usecase?

Comment: A better approach is using UWP APIs from WPF. Without using app service to communicate two apps. Read [this article](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/) for how.

Comment: Thanks, if that works that would indeed be a much better approach!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself, if you keep the AppServiceConnection alive, it will be routed to the same instance in the AppService later on.

Comment: This was the answer to the question I asked, but kennyzx comment was the real answer.